# Pull request from feature branch to master, disappears

Tags: bitbucket-server, subgit

We are experiencing following issue while merging the pull request in our Stash repo.

Scenario:
- Developer creates a feature branch from existing "master/Dev" and submits a pull request to reviewer
- Reviewer, checks and accepts by clicking on "Merge"
- Merge goes through successfully with a new "Commit ID" on Master branch, but within couple of minutes the "Commit ID" on "Master branch" disappears (See Attached images).
- When I do it the other way (Pull request from Master to feature branch) everything works fine.
- I even tried disabling all my "SVN hooks" and I still see the issue. Even the "daemon.0.log" shows nothing.
- I am pretty sure this exception is caused by Subgit. When I shutdown the mirror I see no issues.

Can you please help us resolve the issue.

Thanks,
smandadi[image]

Comment: Hi Siva, you might want to contact the Subgit team directly and see if they can help. http://subgit.com/stash/

Comment: The discussion moved to SubGit issue tracker: http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SG-100

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Stash recommends using "SVN mirror plugin" (Dev by Atalassian + Subgit group) over Subgit tool. Looks like the tool has some glitches while working with Atlassian Stash.

Solution:
1. When using Stash, please use "SVM mirror Plugin" instead of subgit.
2. If you have your system already setup with Subgit + Stash, then just download "SVN mirror plugin" and enable it.
(Please refer to issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SG-100 for more info.)

Thanks [Semyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065967/vadishev) for the help.